# matplotlib scatter cannot use time as x axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time, scatter

I need to use matplotlib, scatter to draw a figure, which uses time as x asix. An example is like this:

```
t=pd.DataFrame({'Time':pd.to_datetime(['07:42:34','08:01:20','10:12:32','14:20,37','18:36:27']).time,
                'Num':[3,3,3,3,3]})
```

When I draw a line using the following code:

```
plt.plot(t.loc[:,'Time'],t.loc[:,'Num'])
plt.show()
```

The figure looks ok:

[image]

But if I use the following code to draw a scatter figure:

```
plt.scatter(t.loc[:,'Time'],t.loc[:,'Num'])
plt.show()
```

Then I have the following error information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3378, in      scatter
    edgecolors=edgecolors, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1717, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4032, in scatter
    alpha=alpha
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 878, in __init__
    Collection.__init__(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 149, in __init__
    offsets = np.asanyarray(offsets, float)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 544, in asanyarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'
```

I am interested in why this happens and how to draw a scatter graph using time as x axis. I want just time, no date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataFrame.plot` deals with datetime properly when plotting lines, but tends to have issues with other types of plots like `bar` and `scatterplot`

A somewhat cheap and simple workaround is to just use `kind='line'` (which is default) and set the linewidth to zero and specify a marker.

```
t.plot(x='Time', y='Num', lw=0, marker='o', figsize=(8,4))
```

[image]